# Authentication failed: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalArgumentException: scopes cannot be null or empty

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I don't understand why Scopes are required. Getting a token aways seems to require scopes. I get this error:

```
Authentication failed: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalArgumentException: scopes cannot be null or empty
```

when calling

```
IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication.acquireToken
```

From a native android app.

In my Azure B2C Application settings, I have "Web App / Web API - Include web app / web API" set to "No". The information says: "Choose 'Yes' if this is a web application" and "Native client - Include native client" set to "Yes". The information about this says: "Choose 'Yes' if this is a native client. For example, a mobile or a desktop app".

I go to Published Scopes in Azure B2C for my Application and see: "Web app / Web API has not been included".

Since I cannot include Published Scopes as I was only trying to get this working on a Native Android Mobile App and I cannot call 'acquireToken' without scopes, I am not sure how to proceed.

Any background on scopes would be helpful as well.  I am not really sure what 'Scopes' are. From what I have read they are fine grained permissions included in OAuth 2.0. I suppose it is up to the app, webapi, etc to actually implement them.

Comment: What kind of token do you need to get? Scopes identify if you want an id token or access token, and in the case of an access token, the permissions.

Comment: I need to do two things in the app, authenticate and then access web apis. I was working on the first one as it has been challenging to get it working. I just did a quick test building one of the APIs, but they are far from ready. In trying to start with Native Client, I ran across the Scopes question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a better understanding please take a look to [B2C Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#scopes).

For B2C you can use openid scope if you want to get an [id token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#token-types) which is used mostly for authentication. If you want to get an access token then you have to [configure scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=applications#configure-scopes) (this aplies to web or native applications) for your B2C application registration and then use them in your token requests.

Regarding the permission problem:

1. Here is a native application created in the legacy app registration experience:

[image]

2. Use the preview app registration

[image]

3. Add your custom scope

[image]

4. Add your custom scope as permission to be included in your tokens.

[image]

Comment: That's a good article. I ran through it before but it was difficult to digest. I wanted to see what the Scope needed to be for the "Native Client' in the Azure Portal for AAD B2C, as you cannot create a Scope with this setting on and the "Web App/Web API" on. It may be implicit in this: "If the response_type parameter in an /authorize request includes token, the scope parameter must include at least one resource scope other than openid and offline_access that will be granted. Otherwise, the /authorize request fails." This seems to imply that there is an implicit scope even if not configured.

Comment: @lcj no implicit scope, just telling us that we need to add a (resource) scope for the access token to be retrieved. openid and offline_access are required for id and refresh tokens. Ok now its clear what's your issue. That happens if you use the legacy app registration. Try the new (preview) one. I'm updating my answer with some pics.

Comment: Thank you!!! That did it. The authentication worked. There is clearly a lot I need to understand here, but that was a great help. Quick question, I know you named your scope SampleScope, but could you have named it SignIn or something like that? Presumably you need scopes for each of the permissions you might grant in the application, right? If you were only granting access to the app and really just had one level of permissions it might be something like SignIn or Authenticate, correct?

Comment: If you had multiple permissions, you would create those as Scopes and give permissions for those, right? And considering those were associated with B2C you might have different Scopes/Permissions for different roles, correct?

Comment: @lcj yes you can name anything you want and create all the ones you need and also group them by logical (your application) roles.

Comment: Thank you. Would your scopes map to access to functions or roles? A user might have multiple roles and those roles might determine the access they have to features within the system. A feature, let's say it's a WebAPI, would have to determine if the person requesting to access the specific scope required, right? That would be done from within the API, correct? So do you create a Scope for the function or the role. I'm leaning towards role. How would you do it?

Comment: @lcj The mapping is up to the authentication and/or authorization software or to you. Right on 2 and 3. For .NET Core take a look to [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue without adding a scope inside AzureAD Portal by using my client-id as Scope type:

```
public static List<String> getScopes() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            "your-client-id-here");
}
```